# Do type matchups have an effect?

Tags: pokemon-duel

There are some plates and figure abilities that give bonuses to various types, but I have not observed any effect (increased damage, decreased miss chance, for example) in matchups where I would expect one figure to have a disadvantage (water v. fire, fire v. grass). Do type matchups between figures have any effect in the actual battle screen in Pokémon Duel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are no type advantages/disadvantages like in traditional Pokémon games. A water type does not do 2x damage against a Fire type, it will just do normal damage.

Type can still matter for building your team, though. For example, the Pokémon Manaphy will boost all friendly water-type Pokémon to do more damage. So making a water-type team around Manaphy can be effective.